# SQL Server running script with Execute causes permission error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure  Which we call it `Test` here.

For simplicity I modified the SP code to:

```
Select * from table A
```

I can run this SP without any issues.

Now if I use Dynamic SQL

```
@SQL='Select * from table A'

EXECUTE (@SQL)

I get 
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'A', database 'MyDb', schema 'dbo'.
```

What is different here?

Comment: should be `Select * from [table A]`

Comment: does this really matter in this case?

Comment: I put brackets , same permission error.

Comment: Then again Why 'select * from A' works?

Comment: because this is the correct syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic SQL has this restriction/limitation. When you use dynamic sql inside a stored procedure , even if the calling user has the permissions on the stored procedure , the user also need permissions on the tables/objects being called inside the dynamic sql .

You have two options

1. Do not use Dynamic sql at all.
2. Give the calling user permissions on the table being used inside the dynamic sql.

Comment: ahhh, interesting , +1

Comment: If you choose option 2, give them the minimum permissions they need. So if you are only going to select from tables, only give select permissions not write or delete permissions.

Comment: Not a response I wanted to hear since my SP will be much more complicated! But the Fact is the Fact!

Answer (score 0):

> This error comes when the user does not have the sufficient privileges
>   to access your tables in the database. Do grant the privilege to the
>   user in order to get what you want.

[Grant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258909(SQL.80).aspx) The Permission For `Select statement(or any other if you want)`.

Comment: The question is If the Permission is the issue then why the non-Dynamic SQL works and Dynamic does not work. What is the difference in terms of permissions.

Comment: see @m.ali's answer, explained very well.